# select first login time every day for each user

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have employee attendence data.I want to find total count of login times in a month for user where logintime<10.30.

One more condition is i should find first login time of each day.
I could succeed finding by writing following query. But I am not able to find total count of 'valid' logins for a month

```
SELECT employee_code,
       MIN(sync_date_time) AS minimum,
       DATE_FORMAT(sync_date_time,'%Y-%m-%d') AS day
FROM `attendance_records`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sync_date_time,'%H:%i:%s') > '00:00:00' AND
      DATE_FORMAT(sync_date_time,'%H:%i:%s') < '10:30:00' AND
      sync_date_time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND
      sync_date_time <= '2017-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY employee_code,day
```

This will give me following results

[image]

Which part of query i should modify?

EDIT1:

Sample Data

[image]

Expected output

[image]

It should not show count as '4' for 9899 as he logged in 2 times on 2018-01-02

Comment: without seeing your table structure and data it is difficult to tell for what you have asked.

Comment: Make sure to read this first: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: I gave you answer below, but if it's wrong, it's because you never showed us the exact output you want.  If so, then please show us the output you expect here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a `GROUP BY` on the `employee_code` only:

```
SELECT employee_code,
       MIN(sync_date_time) AS first_login_time,
       count(distinct date(sync_date_time)) AS emp_count
FROM attendance_records
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sync_date_time,'%H:%i:%s') > '00:00:00' AND
      DATE_FORMAT(sync_date_time,'%H:%i:%s') < '10:30:00' AND
      sync_date_time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'             AND
      sync_date_time <= '2017-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY employee_code
```

Comment: this gives me total count of login times. If employee has logged in 2 times in a day I should consider first login.

Comment: What does that even mean?  Edit your question with a) sample data, and b) the expected output.  Don't leave everyone guessing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think you just need to add more one column with  MIN(sync_date_time) AS minimum

Comment: @krishnpatel Let's see what happens now :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to count distinct date for each employee.

Try this:

```
select 
    employee_code,
    count(distinct date(sync_date_time)) cnt
from your_table t
where date_format(sync_date_time,'%H:%i:%s') > '00:00:00' and
  date_format(sync_date_time,'%H:%i:%s') < '10:30:00' and
  sync_date_time >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00' and
  sync_date_time <= '2017-01-31 23:59:59'
group by employee_code;
```